# access visible properties in actionscript in flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I am using Flash builder 4.5  and migrating the flex code from flex 3 to flex 4.5 and i has done all the thing which is required and mention on this link http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/migrating-flex-apps-part1.html and my application is working fine but i am getting some warning when i am accessing my custom component in ActionScript(handle) using id of that component then it is showing warning like "Access of undefined property visible". below i am giving the code which i am using .

ParentComp.mxml

```
<mx:VBox 
             xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
             xmlns:comp="com.view.ChildComponent" 
 >
  <comp:ChildComponent id="childComp" visible="false" includeInLayout="false"/>   
</mx:VBox>
```

ParentCompHandler.as

```
private function setChildComp(event : PMEvent) : void {
   childComp.visible=true;                             Line:10
   childComp.includeInLayout = true;                   Line:11
}
```

in Line:10 and Line:11 is showing the warning like "Access of undefined property visible".
what wrong i am doing . thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: I don't undestand your full architecture.  It sounds like you have two components; is that true?  If so; `ParentcompHandle` will need to access `ParentCompInstance.childComp.visible` .  Although that is a break in encapsulation principles and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: What does ChildComp extend ?

Comment: To make sense of the error message, we need to know what class ChildComp extends, as FlexFiend has already stated. This doesn't seem like a Flex 3 to Flex 4 migration issue (you would get the same error in Flex 3), unless you changed the class that ChildComp extends during your migration.

Comment: Thanks all for reply , Same thing is working in Flex3 but in Flex4.5 showing warning . anyways i have found the work round for it.